# ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: java, eclipse

I looked this up everywhere already but I failed to find something for my case. What I found was all about this error occurring with some of the Java libraries. On the contrary, my exception is about my own classes. I had a nice project, which I downloaded complete as part of an assignment. It was working fine, of course. It is an OS project which needs to use a class to load a kernel. I didn't modify any of these files - but suddenly it is NOT working anymore, it throws the error when trying to find one of the classes needed. The class is of course still there. The only thing I did was update at some point to JDK 8, so my first thought was to uninstall. Nothing. Clueless, I system restored (yeah I'm very desperate to fix this quickly). Nothing again. No clue how to fix this. By the way, I use Eclipse. Anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your project configuration, make sure your `src` folder is on the build path, make sure you rebuilt your project and everything compiles OK. Look into the run configuration, make sure everything is in order there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate a bit more? I never really needed to mess with those settings, so I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: In the 'Package Explorer' (typically on your left) select the top of the hierarchy, right click for context menu, select 'Properties'. Explore. Run configurations are available through 'Run' menu.

Comment: Done that and everything was alright, in the end I found out that class was supposed to be in the default package... damn. Thanks!